# Фиксация картинки на резиновом фоне

Tags: html, css

Как можно фиксировать `div` в определенном месте на фоне в разных размерах страницы?

```css
body {
  background: url(https://www.ytrecruit.com/images/bg1.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
div.block {
  position: fixed;
  left: 50px;
  top: 50px;
}
img.blockimg {
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div class="block">
<img class="blockimg" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/71/MA_Route_1.svg">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Сначала надо в `style` блока `.block` передать значение `position: absolute;`

Дальше нужно использовать js(в своем случае я использую библиотеку jQuery), чтоб все точно отработало как надо при любом раскладе.

Итак, сначала нам надо определить размер окна при его запуске(чтоб учесть диагональ любого окна). Для этого я воспользуюсь данным кодом:

```
var sizeOfWidth = $(document).width();
var sizeOfHeight = $(document).height();
```

Эти переменные будут хранить значения размера окна.
Теперь, зная размер окна, мы можем задать нужные нам значения(пусть див будет по центру) для нашего блока(размер которого 50% в высоту и ширину от размера окна):

```
$('.block').css('margin-left', sizeOfWidth/4);
$('.block').css('margin-top', sizeOfHeight/4);
```

То есть я передал в `style` блока `.block` значения `margin-top: 25%;`, `margin-left: 25%;`.